# Various ways of executing binaries and scripts and their differences

Tags: bash

If `<script/binary>` is either a script or an executable binary file, which of the following commands can be used to execute it? If there are more than one way, how do they differ?

```bash
$ <script/binary>
$ ./<script/binary>
$ sh <script/binary>
$ source <script/binary>
$ . <script/binary>
```

Are there further ways?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following commands are the same, a dot component means "current directory". To allow for being executed, the files need to have executable permissions:

```
path/to/binary
./path/to/binary
```

Note that if a path does not contain a slash, it is treated as a command (either a shell built-in or a program that is looked up in the `$PATH` environment variable).

The following are almost the same, they execute a **shell script** (not a binary!) in the current shell environment. A small difference between the two lines are described on this [Unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17815/8250).

```
. path/to/script
source path/to/script
```

Finally you mentioned `sh script`. Again, this only works for **shell scripts** and not binaries. You are basically executing the `sh` program with the script name as argument. In the case of `sh`, it just treats this argument as shell script and executes it.

For answers restricted to shellscripts, see [Different ways to execute a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/8250).

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to answer my own question.

**Executing:**

```
$ file          # when 'file' is on the PATH, or is a built-in
$ ./file        # when 'file' is in the current directory
$ /home/me/file
```

`file`, a binary or a script, must have execute permissions set.

**Execute commands in `script` with specified shell**

```
$ sh script
$ bash script
$ zsh script
```

**Sourcing**

```
$ . script
$ source script
```

Comment: Nice question, but it seems for me you have a few misinterprets in your answer. They are: 1) ./ - is there for a security issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552241/executing-a-command-from-the-current-directory-without-dot-slash-like-command/18552331; 2) $ . script      # execute a script in the current dir. - it does not - it looks for a Command named script. To execute script in cur dir you should do $ . ./script or $ source ./script

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick listing of commands. Note, when I mention PATH, I mean the directories containing programs that the system knows about; you find those with `echo $PATH`, and it will be something like: `/home/mike/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

**Scripts**

- To execute a script in current working directory, use `./myscript.sh`
- To execute a script on another file, use (if it is in the current working directory),  `./myscript.sh textfile.txt`
- Scripts can also be run with arguments; as explained in [Rute](http://wireless.ictp.trieste.it/school_2003/docs/linux/rute.pdf) (p. 68): `myfile.sh dogs cats birds` will output `The first argument is: dogs, second argument is: cats, third argument is: birds` because the content of this script after the shebang is: `echo "The first argument is: $1, second argument is: $2, third argument is: $3"`
- To execute a script in another directory, use `~/Scripts/dogs.sh`
- To execute a script that the system knows about because it is in your bin folder in your home directory (just create it if it isn't there, as it will automatically be added to your PATH), just use `scriptname`
- To execute a script you have installed, again just use its name, because it will be known to the system: for example,  `get_iplayer`

**Binaries**

- To run a binary that the system knows about because it is in $PATH, use the name of the program and any parameters, for example, `vlc <stream url to open>`
- To test a binary you have compiled before installing to /usr/local/bin, or to keep a standalone program away from the system, use `~/<folder>/app/myprog`

Comment: Thanks for info. Is this statement correct: To execute a script or binary not in PATH one simply specifies its path. The reason ./ is needed for a script in the current path is that just 'script.sh' would be interpreted as a command since it lacks at least one slash /.

Comment: "To execute a script you have installed", what is a script that I "have installed"? Does this point say the same than the previous point?

Comment: @Carl- your first comment is correct, but it is not true to say that my last two points about scripts are the same. In point 5 of the script section I was talking about scripts that the user has manually added to their bin folder in their home directory; in point 6 I was talking about scripts such as get_iplayer that they have installed from the repositories and as such always go into system folders, not into the user's home directory.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand that, a script in ~/bin/ (which is in PATH) or in a system folder (which is in PATH) - how can there be a difference between them? Do they behave differently?

Comment: I was just making a distinction between those scripts that the user owns and adds to in ~/bin and those that are owned by root in the system folders.